# Is there any sendMail module in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am investigating an old Python code-base written by others. There are multiple references of `from sendMail import sendMail` in the source. If I try to install the module by running `sudo pip install sendmail`, the error thrown is:

```
Collecting sendmail
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sendmail (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sendmail
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 x64 anf Python 2.7.6. Does anybody have a clue how to install this dependency?

Comment: I would guess it's a local python module made by the same people who wrote the code you are investigating. As far as I know, there are no public python packages with the name sendMail

Comment: Probably a thin wrapper around https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

Comment: This one? https://lab.nexedi.com/tiwariayush/erp5/blob/10e148caa3a3e6f53dce1f6cd093846b45562dae/product/ERP5Type/tests/sendMail.py